# .NET WPF Determine which Datagrid is selected

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have an application that uses 5 Datagrids on one UserControl. What would be the best way to go about restricting the user to only be allowed to select one datagrid at a time. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you refer to "select[ing] only one datagrid at a time", do you have a concrete picture in your mind of what that would mean in user interface terms? Is only one of them enabled? Is only one of them visible?

Comment: Yes I do. All grids are enabled at the same time. The program functions as a live data board that constantly refreshes. Users can select a row on any of these grids at any time and make changes to the record which will then move the record to a different grid.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're having?

Comment: A user will select a record and choose an action to complete. The problem is that there are currently five active selections that the user could be referring to.

Comment: Give each record an extra column containing "Actions" buttons that pop up a context menu for that row in that grid. Done.

Answer (score 0):

you could some radiobuttons, representing your datagrids, I'm wondering a screen like:

```
() radiobutton for Datagrid 1

*----------------------------*
|   datagrid 1               |
|                            |
*----------------------------* 

() radiobutton for Datagrid 2

*----------------------------*
|   datagrid 2               |
|                            |
*----------------------------*
```

Datagrids IsEnabled are binded to corresponding radiobutton, this way you have one Datagrid only enabled per time.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: All of my datagrids are enabled at the same time. The application is filled with live data and the user can select any grid at any given time

Comment: I have been able to do this before; however, it was not very clean.

Comment: Yes; however, we MUST go with this design as our customers want to see all 5 grids at one time

Answer (score 0):

You said you said: "*A user will select a record and choose an action to complete. The problem is that there are currently five active selections that the user could be referring to*". My solution allows user to see all 5 grids.

Another idea would be your action button pop up other options, allowing user to pick up the correct grid he wants.

[image]